# Facebook Graph API/FQL to check whether user liked a post

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios6, facebook-fql

I'm using FQL to determine if a user has liked a post or not. When the user hasn't liked any post the response is good enough but it remains the same when the post is liked, I don't get the user's(my) `user_id` in response.

Here's what I did:(inside the granted block after getting `read_stream` permission)

```
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/fql"];
    NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary
                                    dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select user_id from like where object_id=%@ AND user_id=me()",postID], @"q", nil];
    SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                            requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                      URL:requestURL
                                               parameters:params];
    request.account = [[self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountTypeFacebook] objectAtIndex:0];
    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                         NSHTTPURLResponse *response,
                                         NSError *error) {

        if(!error){
            NSDictionary *resultDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
            resultDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
            NSLog(@"dictionary with user id's: %@",resultDictionary);
        }else{
          //handle error gracefully
        }
     }];
```

Output (when post is not liked):

```
{
    data =     (
    );
}
```

Output (when post is liked):

```
{
    data =     (
    );
}
```

I tried passing id of the post and in query using `post_id` inplace of `object_id`, but no success.

Answer (score 1):

To check whether user liked a post we need to get data form stream table instead of like table, please follow the below request

```
Request : 
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/fql"];
                                                       NSMutableDictionary * params1 = [NSMutableDictionary
                                                                                        dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT likes FROM stream WHERE post_id = '%@'",postID], @"q",facebookOfflineAccessToken,@"accessToken",nil];
```

Response : you will get `"user_likes" = 0` for not liked,`"user_likes" = 1` for like